# How to fill in extra grid items in empty spaces?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-grid

**CONTEXT:**
I currently have a bunch of divs (about 80) being populated into a container that is meant to be overflowing horizontally (for Scrolling) with these items. Some of these are just coloured div squares while some of these items are divs elements with text (p) in it. As is usually the case, these words could be long or some are short, so I cannot explicitly say how long to span these items in the grid. I don't know where the location of these text elements will be because they come in dynamically through javascript. I'm new to css grid.

**MY PROBLEM:**

I don't know how to make the current grid fill the empty spaces with sqaure divs, currently they just expand to the max width of column - that is being stretched by the word length.

**CSS NAMING:**
The divs with text have a class `.textbox` while box divs have a class `.box`.

**HOW IT LOOKS**
[image: HOW IT LOOKS]

**HOW I WANT IT TO LOOK**
[image]

CSS CODE

```
.containerMed {
   width: 1500px;
   position: relative;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   display: grid;
   gap: 5px;
   padding: 2.5px;
   grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
   grid-auto-flow: column dense;
}

.box{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    grid-row-end: span 1;
    grid-row-end: span 1;
}

.textbox {
   font-size: 33px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   line-height: 0.8;
}
```

JSX CODE

```
function GridPattern(props) {
   let lineup = ["Oneohtrix Point Never", "Kilo Kish", "Sudan Archives","L'Rain"," Weyes Blood","Pussy Riot", "Serpentwithfeet","Jacques Greene","Envelop", "Telefon Tel Aviv","Julianna Barwick"]

   let n = Array.from(Array(80).keys())
   const boxes = n.map((num) => {
       if (num % 9 === 0)
          return <div key={num} className="textbox" style={{ color: props.color }}>. 
          <p>{lineup[num % 12]}</p></div>
       else 
          return <div key={num} className={props.pattern} style={{ backgroundColor: 
                 props.color }}></div>
   })

   return boxes
}

function App() {
<div className="containerMed" style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', height: '250px'}}>
               <GridPattern pattern="box"  color='blue'></GridPattern>
            </div>
  }
```

Comment: If you don't want your squares to align vertically -- your image of what you want shows that they align horizontally but not vertically -- then I wouldn't use a grid at all. However, if you **do** want your squares to align vertically, then the text "SerpentWithFeet" needs to **span** eight grid columns. `grid-column: 1 / span 8;` The right hand column on this webpage explains how you can get elements to span multiple grid columns and/or rows. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: what would you use instead?

Comment: of grid? would it be flexbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the look you've illustrated, I wouldn't bother with either grid or flexbox, just use regular inline blocks and turn off the wrapping.

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #a7e7a1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #22946e;
  padding: 10px;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
i {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #a7e7a1;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  margin: 0 0.2rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
span {
  margin: 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>

<p><i></i><i></i><span>Fred</span><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>David<i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></p>

<p><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><span>James</span><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></p>

<p><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><span>William</span><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></p>

<p><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><span>Norman</span><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></p>

<p><i></i><i></i><i></i><span>Paul</span><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>Matthew<i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></p>

</div>
```